# Convert Char to ASCII code in Fay

Tags: haskell, fay

Is there a way to convert values of type `Char` to their numerical ASCII codes in Fay?

(The Haskell Prelude offers the function `fromEnum` and the equivalent function `ord`, but I don't see anything similar in the Fay Prelude.)

The documentation for the `fay-base` package notes a lot of type classes, but since Fay doesn't support type classes, I assume that `fromEnum` is not supported either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data.Char` isn't in fay-base yet (see https://github.com/faylang/fay/issues/377) and there is only an enum instance for `Int`, but I'll add ord and chr. Here's how to do it until then:

```
chr :: Int -> Char
chr = ffi "String.fromCharCode(%1)"

ord :: Char -> Int
ord = ffi "%1.charCodeAt(0)"
```